# get renderd javascript lines from website in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-3.6, python-requests-html

I'm using python 3.6.6 for this.

I'm trying to get the current versionnumber of pycharm from the pycharm website (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows).
The versionnumber is displayed pretty obvious, still I can't get it because I don't know how to process java script properly.

I tried parsing it out with requests_html from:

```
<li>Version: <span data-code="PCP" data-release-version=""></span></li>
```

This part should look like this after java script has done its job:

```
<li>Version: <span data-code="PCP" data-release-version="">2018.1.4</span></li>
```

Here is my not working script by the way:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows')


r.html.render()
item = r.html.find('<span data-code="PCP" data-release-version=""></span>')


print(item)
```

I don't care if there would be any parts left over, I would simply filter them out with RegEx. Still the only thing I'm getting from this is:

```
[<Element 'span' data-code='PCP' data-release-version=''>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

I found an solution my self. It seems like render() is in need for sleep. Also I used xpath instead of search.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows')


r.html.render(sleep=0.1)
item = r.html.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/span/text()')

print('------------------------------------------------')
print(item)
```

my Result:

```
['2018.1.4']
```

Comment: This helped me solved my issue! Any idea why sleep was required?

Comment: @BernardL Render opens up chromium in the backround. It probably tries getting the script stuff to fast and therefore is only getting the html in it's raw form. Sleep gives chromium some time to load the javascript before getting it.