# Scraping a single li from a webpage using Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and web scraping. 
I am trying to get the build number from the jetbrains website for intellij. I am trying to scrape the build number using xpath. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux
xpath //*[@id="download-block"]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/text()[3]

I have referenced/used the code from this post:
[get renderd javascript lines from website in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403755/get-renderd-javascript-lines-from-website-in-python/59469318#59469318)

After I run the code I return  [ ] 
I have tried it with the OP code and the same result is returned.
I have been able to use Beautiful Soup to print out the entire page but I only need the build number.

Any help or a kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
   from requests_html import HTMLSession
   session = HTMLSession()

   r = session.get('https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux')
   r.html.render(sleep=0.1)
   item = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="download-block"]/section[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/text()[3]')

   print(item)
```

Comment: This is not working, since the website is dynamic and Javascript is disabled in chromium, You can verify that by printing text of the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What would scrape the build number from the webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://data.services.jetbrains.com/products/releases?code=IIU&latest=true&type=release',
    headers={'authority': 'data.services.jetbrains.com',
             'accept': 'application/json',
             'origin': 'https://www.jetbrains.com',
             'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
             'referer': 'https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/'}
)

print(r.json()['IIU'][0]['build'])
```

Jetbrains does not support browser having Javascript disabled as data is fetched from a different server.  To work around this we can directly download the data from that site.